# What is the plus (+) symbol in Objective-c #import instructions?

Tags: objective-c

For example:

```
#import "NSArray+BBNSArrayAdditions.h"
```

I've tried googling it and looking on the apple developer documentation but I can't find an explanation.

A link or explanation of any other import tokens would also be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: It's convention for a category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just file name : `NSArray+BBNSArrayAdditions.h` but in Objective C there is a 'standard' to name categories as: class name (class you want to write category for) plus sign and your custom category name, for example;

```
NSString+MyCategoryName.h
```

Comment: Ah I see.  I've just found this for those looking for information on categories (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3)

Thanks